# Elasticsearch bulk index error on Sonar startup

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube5.6

Would someone be able to assist on the error below?  It is occurring on the start up of SonarQube 5.6 running on Java 8u71 and an Oracle database.  This instance was just update from 5.2.  I had the Puppet addon and uninstalled it as an attempt to solve the error.  I confirm Elasticsearch is on port 9001 after startup.

```
2016.06.13 00:16:04 ERROR web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] Fail to execute bulk index request: Bulk[671 index request(s) on index rules and type activeRule]
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [sonar-1465791343547][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]][indices:data/write/bulk]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: The provided routing value [puppet] doesn't match the routing key stored in the document: [puppet:ArrowsAlignment]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest.process(IndexRequest.java:577) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.executeBulk(TransportBulkAction.java:236) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.doExecute(TransportBulkAction.java:167) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportBulkAction.doExecute(TransportBulkAction.java:67) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:75) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.HandledTransportAction$TransportHandler.messageReceived(HandledTransportAction.java:63) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.HandledTransportAction$TransportHandler.messageReceived(HandledTransportAction.java:51) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleRequest(MessageChannelHandler.java:222) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:114) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error is fixed in version 6.0. Meanwhile you should delete the directory $SONAR_HOME/data/es/ and restart server. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  Would know the JIRA ticket for it so I may watch?