# Sonarqube Error when activating rules in new Quality Profile

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube5.6

I'm using SonarQube server version 5.6.1 in docker. I have correctly configured the default Quality Profiles but now when trying to activate existing rules in a new Quality profile, the application throws the following error in the log:

```
ERROR web[o.s.s.es.BulkIndexer] Fail to execute bulk index request: Bulk[1 index request(s) on index rules and type activeRule] org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [sonar-470917037901][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]][indices:data/write/bulk] Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: The provided routing value [squid] doesn't match the routing key stored in the document: [squid:S2204]
```

Do any of you have an idea of what could be happening? The rule appears as active in that profile but the profile says 0 active rules.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find another question that contains a lookalike problem like mine in: [Elasticsearch bulk index error on Sonar startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781951/elasticsearch-bulk-index-error-on-sonar-startup).
Tried the same answer and it worked.

TL;DR Delete the directory $SONAR_HOME/data/es/ and restart server.